# Why do the black balls floating on top of the water surface form lattice strctures?

Tags: everyday-life, material-science

The phenomenon I'm asking about can be seen in this [veritusium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxPdPpi5W4o). The balls were just dumped in randomly, and they are buffeted by wind and currents, so how do they settle into clean lattice-like structures? Can the mechanics of this phenomenon be applied to other phenomena?

Answer (score 0):

The "crystals" are likely due to locally jammed structures. Jammed structures show up a lot in granular media when objects are packed together so that they all prevent each other from moving. [As the fraction filled by the spheres increases](http://pablonet.princeton.edu/pgd/papers/prl/prlv84p02064.pdf), they are increasingly forced into locally jammed configurations since there are fewer and fewer options available. [Since the density increases these jammed structures are also regular crystals](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~stte/BSSCM/lecture1.pdf).